# Is this a regularity in primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

For any prime $p$ subtract $24$ continuously. The last value before $0$ will always be one of these $8$ primes:
$\{ 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 \}$.

[Prime Distribution Across Lengths of 24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BqsO.jpg)

[Primes in Blue. Root Prime Path in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA6Wb.jpg)

As can be observed above prime numbers do not deviated from the original host numbers. This suggests that primes have a geometric component underpinning their formation. Further, it should hold true that primes persist to appear in just $8$ or $24$ locations as observed above. 
Consider then:

$24^2 = 576 $

$576$ is the $24$th column of the images above. Subtracting $-1, -5, -7, -11, -13, -17, -19$ or $-23$ should then result in a prime hit or miss.

$-1$ is a miss

$-5$ is a hit: $571$ …a prime

$-7$ is a hit: $569$ …a prime

$-11$ is a miss

$-13$ is a hit: $563$ …a prime

$-17$ is a miss

$-19$ is a hit: $557$ …a prime

$-23$ is a miss

Now, let’s do this with arbitration:

Choose a large number: 
$1024169726$

The nearest prime to $1024169726$ is $1024169717$.

$1024169726 – 1024169717 = 9$.

This would seem to violate what I have stated above. However, $1024169726$ is not divisible by $24$.

$1024169726 – 14 = 1024169712$.

$1024169712$ is divisible by $24$.

$1024169717 - 1024169712 = 5$, one of the prime conditions stated above in this sieve.

Again, choosing from arbitration a number: $3248715756$.
$3248715756 + 12 = 3248715768$ which is divisible by $24$.

$\dfrac{3248715768} {24} = 135363157$.

$3248715768 – 1, -5, -7, -11, -13, -17, -19, -23$ does not produce primes.

$3248715768 – 24 = 3248715744.$

$3248715744 – 13 = 3248715733$ which is prime.

Here we can see again that while there are not always primes within the gaps of $24$ the primes will nevertheless occur along the vector issued by adding $24$ to $\{ 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 \}$ continuously.

This hypothesis was formed by myself and another professor at Penn State by investigating the mathematics behind old astrological sites such as Knowth. Unfortunately our network of Number Theorists from this campus is very small. If anyone can confirm this is indeed a pattern in primes it would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you,
Iapyx

P.S. 
This website's formatting doesn't allow the original spacing in the numerical formatting. Sorry for the clutter.

Comment: I don't understand.  If $p>3$ is a prime then $\gcd(p,24)=1$.  But every integer prime to $24$ is congruent to exactly one of $\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}$ $\pmod {24}$.

Comment: You two are professors in the humanities at Penn State? Which is more than I can say for myself, of course.

Comment: Apologies. No. I myself am not a professor, but I have had the help of several others. That was what "another" references. I am a graduate of Penn State. My degree IS from Liberal Arts. The professors helping have their work in Mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

This is a regularity to be found whatever the even interval you choose, be it 24, 70892, $17! - 8$, etc.

From [Dirichlet's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletsTheorem.html), we know that $24m + n$ gives infinitely many primes provided $\gcd(24, n) = 1$. Without loss of generality, as the professional mathematicians like to say, we can assume $0 \leq n < 24$.

Now, what's $\gcd(24, 0)$? A vexing question, but it's not 1, I can tell you that much. Indeed we see that $24m + 0$ never gives a prime, because all those numbers are multiples of 24.

Then what about $24m + 1$? You have already gathered evidence that there are a few primes of this form. Dirichlet tells us there are infinitely many primes of this form. He gave a proof, which I have not seen, but I trust real mathematicians have reviewed it and found it to be in order.

$24m + 2$ will not work, though, for any value other than $m = 0$. All numbers of that form, aside from 2 itself, are even and divisible by some prime other than 2. We have a very similar situation with $24m + 3$, only $m = 0$ gives a prime (though it's possible for other numbers of that form to be divisible by no prime other than 3, e.g., if $m = 1$). Both 2 and 3 are divisors of 24, so obviously $\gcd(24, 3) > \gcd(24, 2) > 1$.

Let's skip ahead to $24m + 10$. Clearly 10 is not a divisor of 24, but $\gcd(24, 10) = 2$, and accordingly we find that all numbers of the form $24m + 10$ are even. And with $24m + 18$, we see that not only are all numbers of that form even, they are all divisible by 3 and by 6. That's because $\gcd(24, 18) = 6$.

What if we calculate $\gcd(24, n)$ for $0 < n < 24$? We get the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 8, 3, 2, 1, 12, 1, 2, 3, 8, 1, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1. So the symmetry that you're observing is merely the result of the symmetry of this sequence.

There are wondrous things in math. This is not one of them.

Comment: Don't add. If 24m = 48 then m = 2. 48/2 = 24. The symmetry of a pattern such as you are describing is noise. 24m+1,2 is not divisible by 24. However, the key point here is that 2+24+24+24...+24 may will never arrive upon a prime. Therefore it would follow that { 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24} + (24+24+24...+24) will also never be prime. If true (and I am not inept at writing this properly), all primes are to be found along the course of 24m - {1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19, 23}. This would reduce the search for primes to 8 points of interest within a length of 24 whole #s.

Comment: Also, of the 8 points of interest (if true) this does not tackle the issue of prime gaps. If I understand correctly those can range as far as 70,000,000 in length. Even so, if I could extend this excel sheet far enough I'd still expect the primes to be in just these 8 locations.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that this is simply because $\{ 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 \}$ are the only integers between $0$ and $24$ whose *gcd* (greatest common divisor) with $24$ is $1$. Since $24 = 2^3.3$, whenever $n = m\cdot 24 + k$, $k$ must not be divisible by $2$ or $3$ if $n$ is supposed to be prime. Removing all such numbers from $\{0,\ldots,23\}$ yields exactly the list you found...

Comment: Yes, thank you for saying that kindly. The significance of all of this to me is more down the line of computer-memory problems. If I wanted to make a program to search for primes being able to throw out a huge set of data entries is a real boon. Therefore if by adding 24 to any of {1,5,7,11,13,17,19, 23} continuously I can short-cut my calculations I can find primes MUCH faster. But just to point something out: 431-55 continuously stops at 46 (before 0). So, the set of primes I'm choosing looking at on aren't arbitrary. If it was 431-any value continuously would produce a prime.

Answer (score 2):

The integers $\{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}$ are natural numbers numbers less than $24$ that are co-prime to $24.$

Lets look at the compliment to this set.

$B=\{2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,22\}$

For all $b\in B, \gcd(b,24) \ne 1$

If $k = 24n + b$ then $\gcd(k,24) \ne 1$ and $k$ is not prime.

Furthermore there are composite numbers, that pass your "test."  e.g. $121$ is not prime, and $121 = 24\cdot5+1$

Comment: From what I was able to chart addition cannot work in this system. k=24n+b sets 1 the same as 23. 24n is correct however. That begins the the point of any subtraction. k=24n- b where b = {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23} would work. Addition is only workable in this where choosing an arbitrary whole number does not arrive at number divisible by 24 evenly.

Comment: For every $a\in \{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\}, 24-a$ is also a member of the set.  Everything you have written is symmetric for addition or subtraction.

Comment: I should amend, "Addition cannot work because people who aren't mathematicians forget what value of 24m they are in." This is the KISS-Constraint or something like that. Then they start saying, "This isn't working with the set you gave!" To which I have to tell them, "You either added by a number I did not supply, you have lost track of where you are relative to a number divisible by 24, or you have forgotten there are gaps in primes." I do not make claims to this finding ALL primes. Just where to look for them - which could be entirely wrong.